# List not being written to a text file

Tags: python

I have a program that is supposed to ask how many primes to calculate then write them all to a text file. However, it creates the file then dosen't run.

```
def constantcall():
      j = 2
      chk = 1
      f = open("primes.txt", "w")
      primes = []
      notprimes = []
      ask = input("how many primes? ")
      while len(primes) < int(ask):
            k = 2
      while not(k==j) and not(j%k==0):
            k = k + 1
      if k == j:
            primes.append(j)
            f.write(str(j)+"\n")
      else:
            notprimes.append(j)
      if len(primes) >= 1000*chk:
            chk = chk + 1
            print("There have been " + str(len(primes)) + " primes counted so far")
            j = j + 1
            print("Primes written to file 'primes.txt', " + str(len(primes)) + " written")
            f.close
            return(" ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while(True):
        constantcall()
```

Comment: How are you using this? Why only write results (and not *call* `close`) if there are more than 1000? Why the neverending loop `if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Comment: How are you terminating the program? It's possible that you issue a KeyboardInterrupt or end the program after it opens the file but before it writes to it. Because the mode is 'w', it clears the contents of the file when it opens it.

Comment: @DavidReeve with the len primes > ask line. Should i use w+?

Comment: `f.close` ==> `f.close()`?

Comment: @matsjoyce No difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the code:

```
 while len(primes) < int(ask):
     k = 2
```

at this point `len(primes)` is less than `int(ask)`, and there is nothing that add items to primes, so infinite loop.

Your code must be (in order to avoid infinite loop):

```
def constantcall():
      j = 2
      chk = 1
      f = open("primes.txt", "w")
      primes = []
      notprimes = []
      ask = input("how many primes? ")
      while len(primes) < int(ask):
          k = 2
          while not(k==j) and not(j%k==0):
                k = k + 1
          if k == j:
                primes.append(j)
                f.write(str(j)+"\n")
          else:
                notprimes.append(j)
          if len(primes) >= 1000*chk:
                chk = chk + 1
                print("There have been " + str(len(primes)) + " primes counted so far")
                j = j + 1
                print("Primes written to file 'primes.txt', " + str(len(primes)) + " written")
                f.close
                return(" ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    constantcall()
```

### Using Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm

You could use the algorithm [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

```
def primes(count):
    """
    Returns a list with the first `count` prime numbers.

    An advice: If you will be using this functiona a lot it's better
    for performance if you precalculate cribe.
    """

    # Calculate primes up to 50, you can change this to your preference.
    MAX = 50      

    sieve = [1] * MAX
    for i in range(2, int(MAX ** 0.5) + 2 ):
        for j in range(i + i, MAX, i):
            sieve[j] = 0

    # Finally primes are indexes in the list that still has 0.
    result = []
    for index, elem in enumerate(sieve):
        if elem == 1: result.append(index)

    return result[1:count + 1]
```

Your code can then be rewrited as:

```
def constantcall():
    f = open("primes.txt", "w")
    ask = int(input("how many primes? "))
    prime_numbers = primes(ask)
    f.writelines(map(lambda x: "{0}\n".format(x), prime_numbers))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    constantcall()
```

Comment: Just prints 2 primes times!

Comment: Yes, you need to fix that too. But the problem of the numbers not being writed to the file is fixed.

Comment: @MagikCow Answer edited to help with the other problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does nothing.

```
  while len(primes) < int(ask):
        k = 2
```

Is useless.

```
  while not(k==j) and not(j%k==0):
        k = k + 1
```

Is useless as j is always 2.

```
  if k == j:
        primes.append(j)
        f.write(str(j)+"\n")
  else:
        notprimes.append(j)
```

Here you append `2` to primes once.

```
  if len(primes) >= 1000*chk:
        chk = chk + 1
        print("There have been " + str(len(primes)) + " primes counted so far")
        j = j + 1
        print("Primes written to file 'primes.txt', " + str(len(primes)) + " written")
        f.close()
        return
```

So len(primes) is always 1.

Here is a solution. Sorry for C language, but you could easily pythonize it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned long long ull;

int main(){
ull numb=10000,stop=20000;
ull i,c;
int cnt;
printf("Here are the primes between %lld and %lld :\n\n",numb,stop);
while(numb<=stop){
for(i=1;i<=numb;++i){
if(!(numb%i)) ++cnt;
}
if ((cnt==2) || (i==1)) printf("%lld; ",numb);
cnt=0;
++numb;
}
printf("\n\nThat's all\n");
}
```

Comment: @MagikCow this was just explanation of mistakes